# 3 integers from greatest to least

Tags: c++

I am beginner to C++ and I using "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ (Second Edition). The question asked:
"Write a program that prompts the user to enter three integer values, and then outputs the values in numerical sequence separated by commas. If two values are the same, they should just be ordered together."

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include<conio.h>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    int one; 
    int to; 
    int tree;
    int big = 0;
    int med = 0;
    int tiny = 0;
    cout << "Please enter 3 integer value:\n";
    cin >> one >> to >> tree; 
    {
        if (one > to && to > tree)
            big == one && med == to && tiny == tree;
        if (one > tree && tree > to)
            big == one && med == tree && tiny == to;
        if (to > one && one > tree)
            big == to && med == one && tiny == tree;
        if (to > tree && tree > one)
            big == to && med == tree && tiny == one;
        if (tree > one && one > to)
            big == tree && med == one && tiny == to;
        if (tree > to && to > one)
            big == tree && med == to && tiny == one;
    }
    cout << "Biggest to smallest: "
    << big << ", " << med << ", " << tiny;
    '\n';
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

When I executed it and input '1 2 3', it returns with '0, 0, 0'. Advice, tip, or hints are welcome. Thank you.
Edit: Also, I didn't consider doing the second part of the question yet because I can't figure out the first.

Comment: why `big == one && med == to && tiny == tree;`?

Comment: OH!!!! Thank you. I had to change `==` to `=`, and get rid of the `&&` change into `;`

Comment: Because I can't find any duplicate (doesn't mean there isn't any) I suggest reading the book and doing the other exercises more carefully. That's all.

Comment: another way to approach it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f14b3beb8187c6b

Comment: If you change `==` to `=` and `&&` to `;` you might introduce a new bug. `;` delimits a statement. There is only one statement considered after `if ()` (and formatting might let you oversee this but doesn't change that fact). In this case, don't forget the `{ }`. As assignments are expressions, you could alternatively replace `&&` by `,` (the sequence operator) which makes all three assignments one expression - no need for curly braces in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::sort` (as suggested by Richard) is one solution, though IMHO such heavy gun isn't necessary for a data set of 3 elements. For 3 variables, the sorting can be unrolled (as the OP tried) and the various available sorting algorithms probably differ that much (concerning the order of comparisons and swaps) or won't bring any improvement concerning this little sample.

Thus, I made an unrolled sort (re-sembling what I believe would be bubble sort):

```
#include <iostream>

void sort(int &a, int &b, int &c)
{
  if (a < b) std::swap(a, b);
  if (b < c) std::swap(b, c);
  if (a < b) std::swap(a, b);
}

int main()
{
  // any permutation of { 1, 2, 3 } (i.e. any possible order)
  int tests[][3] = {
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 1, 3, 2 },
    { 2, 1, 3 },
    { 2, 3, 1 },
    { 3, 1, 2 },
    { 3, 2, 1 }
  };
  // apply sort() to every test set
  for (int *test : tests) {
    int a = test[0], b = test[1], c = test[2];
    std::cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << " c: " << c << " sorted: ";
    sort(a, b, c);
    std::cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << " c: " << c << '\n';
  }
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a: 1 b: 2 c: 3 sorted: a: 3 b: 2 c: 1
a: 1 b: 3 c: 2 sorted: a: 3 b: 2 c: 1
a: 2 b: 1 c: 3 sorted: a: 3 b: 2 c: 1
a: 2 b: 3 c: 1 sorted: a: 3 b: 2 c: 1
a: 3 b: 1 c: 2 sorted: a: 3 b: 2 c: 1
a: 3 b: 2 c: 1 sorted: a: 3 b: 2 c: 1
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/720eba6d7c471354)