# Finding the lowest number, which isn't zero

Tags: c++, math

I'm having three integers called a,b,c and need to find the lowest number of them, which isn't 0.
But at the same time it should be able to handle the special case where all the three numbers are 0.

This have to be implemented in C or C++14

**Example 1:**

```
a = 4;
b = 0;
c = 1;

Result = c
```

**Example 2**

```
a = 0;
b = 0;
c = 0;

Result = Special case
```

**Example 3**

```
a = 11;
b = 46;
c = 15;

Result = a
```

So far i haven't been able to find an elegant way to implement this in c or c++.

I've considered to put it in a sorted array, and keep popping the numbers until it get something else than zero. But this seems to be an over-complicated way to do it.

**Edit**

Forgot to mention that the values i try to find is never negative, but always positive.

***Removed the code, since it's should not be a code review***

Comment: the simplest way is the best most of the time

Comment: C and C++ are two *very* different languages, and solutions in each language could be vastly different. So please pick one language and stick to it.

Comment: If this problem is always only 3 numbers I would probably just use nested  if () else ...

Comment: are they integer values?

Comment: Concerning sort: [SO: 3 integers from greatest to least](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51222186/7478597). Just, the check for 0 is missing. If only positive numbers are allowed, the greatest will be 0 in the "Special case".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Then let's say it should just work in C++.

Comment: @norok2 Yes, they are all of the type int.

Comment: From your output I thought you wanted to print 'a' , 'b' or 'c' and not the values. However your solution seems to differ.

Comment: The algorithm from @Someprogrammerdude may be a little faster, although it may just be a wash after the compiler optimizes the code. In either case the amount of time to do this is going to be extremely small. Probably unmeasurable between the alternatives.

Comment: Given the edit, this seems more like a code review? https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ChrisB I can see that now, hence the code is removed again. I'll remember this in the future questions.

Comment: @Allan I do not think it was meant to remove code, but more that if your code is actually having the expected behavior (possibly without major flaws), a better place for posting it may be codereview stackexchange. Stackoverflow should be more for code that it is not working. At least that would be the will of stackexchange crew. My observation is that people would use stackoverflow for both, as codereview seems to enjoy a much much smaller active community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bulk of the control flow could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>


int find_smallest_nonzero(int a, int b, int c)
{
    if (a > 0 || b > 0 || c > 0) {
       if ((b >= a || b == 0) && (c >= a || c == 0) && (a > 0))
           return a;
       else if ((c >= b || c == 0) && (b != 0))
           return b;
       else
           return c;
    } else return -1;
}

int main() {
    std::cout 
            // permutations
            << find_smallest_nonzero(1, 2, 3) << ' '
            << find_smallest_nonzero(2, 1, 3) << ' '
            << find_smallest_nonzero(2, 3, 1) << ' '

            // one zeros
            << find_smallest_nonzero(1, 0, 3) << ' '
            << find_smallest_nonzero(0, 1, 3) << ' '
            << find_smallest_nonzero(1, 3, 0) << ' '

            // two zeros
            << find_smallest_nonzero(1, 0, 0) << ' '
            << find_smallest_nonzero(0, 1, 0) << ' '
            << find_smallest_nonzero(0, 0, 1) << ' '

            // duplicates
            << find_smallest_nonzero(2, 2, 1) << ' '
            << find_smallest_nonzero(2, 1, 2) << ' '
            << find_smallest_nonzero(1, 2, 2) << ' '

            << find_smallest_nonzero(1, 1, 2) << ' '
            << find_smallest_nonzero(1, 2, 1) << ' '
            << find_smallest_nonzero(2, 1, 1) << ' '

            // all zeros
            << find_smallest_nonzero(0, 0, 0) << '\n';
}
```

> ```
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 -1
> ```

it will return the minimum non-zero among `a`, `b` and `c`, unless all are `0`, in which case returns `-1`.

There might be faster ways.

Answer (score 2):

If there is only three values, using simple `if` statements could be a solution.

Then the logic could be (*pseudo-code*)

```
if (a is larger than zero) and (b is larger than zero and a is smaller than b) and (c is larger than zero and a is smaller than c)
    a is the smallest
else if (b is larger than zero) and (c is larger than zero and b is smaller than c)
    b is the smallest
else if c is larger than zero
    c is the smallest
else
    all are either zero or negative
```

Note that each `if` check gets progressively smaller. That's because the previous condition removes an alternative that doesn't need to be checked further.

This of course works for larger chains of variables, as long as the amount of variables is fixed. It will become unwieldy quite fast though, so for more than three-four variables other methods should be used.

Comment: `a = 1`, `b = 0`, `c = 0` will fail to return `a` as the minimum. You also need to check that whatever you are comparing to is also not zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
int lowest(int a, int b, int c) {
    auto v = {a, b, c};
    return *std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [](int x, int y) {
        return (x < y && x != 0) || y == 0;
    });
}
```

This approach can handle any number of elements. In the special case, the function simply returns zero (there is no need to use a different special value).

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following in C++ using [std::min](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min)

> ```
> int a = 0,b = 0,c = 0;
> int x = std::min( { a,b,c },
>         [](const auto& n1, const auto& n2) {
>              if (not n1)
>                return false;
>              if (not n2)
>                return true;
>              return n1 < n2;
>          });
> std::string out = x?std::to_string(x):std::string{"Special Case"};
> ```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(a==0 && b==0 && c==0){
    return "Special case"
}else{
    // now put each equals zero and compare the other, last else compare all three
}
```

You can write a function printf the output.

Comment: "now put each equals zero and compare the other" can you elaborate this a bit ?