# Finding the minimum and maximum number from rearranging digits without using arrays and strings

Tags: c++

So i have a task that i'm supposed to find the max and minimum number by rearranging given number.

The hard part is that, in this task especially i'm not allowed to use arrays,vectors and string into array way.

Example:

`Input: 598`
`Output: 589, 985`

I done that, but only using the array, that sort every number by desc and asc.
Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num;
    int dec;
    bool flag = false;
    int curNum;
    vector<int> numbers;
    
    cout << "Enter three digit number:  ";
    cin >> num;

    while (num > 0) {
        curNum= num % 10;
        num /= 10;
        flag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < chisla.size(); ++i) {
            if (numbers[i] > curNum) {
                flag = true;
                numbers.insert(numbers.begin() + i, curNum);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!flag) numbers.push_back(curNum);
    }

    // Сортиране на масива, като се подрежда в низходящ ред.
    sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), greater<int>());

   
    dec = 1;
    int min_val = 0;
    for (auto &it : numbers) {
        min_val += it * dec;
        dec *= 10;
    }

    sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());

    dec = 1;
    int max_val = 0;
    for (auto &it : numbers) {
        max_val += it * dec;
        dec *= 10;
    }

    cout << "е: \n"
         << (max_val - min_val) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So the main question is there any way to that without arrays, sorting and etc. (Don't ask why i can't use them, just the current task don't allow that.)

Thanks in advance.

Wish u all good.

Comment: Is the problem limited to the 3-digit case, or does the code need to support longer numbers too?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Only 3 digit case

Comment: Then just read the three digits one at a time into three variables and sort them "manually."  There are not many possibilities with only three digits.

Comment: So, you want this done without using the `std::vector` you're currently using. A single three-node swap network would give you want you want, and require only three test and swap operations. Then report the results in both forward and reverse order and you're done.

Comment: Concerning sorting 3 integers: [SO: 3 integers from greatest to least](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51222186/7478597)

Comment: I find a way to that. Please see the answer below!

Comment: The linked answer in the comment from @Scheff is *exactly* the three-node swap network I referred to earlier.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it in that way.

```
    int a,b,c,temp,x=123;
    a = x/100;
    b = (x/10)%10;
    c = x%10;
    if(b>a){
        temp=a;
        a=b;
        b=temp;
    }
    if(c>b){
        temp=b;
        b=c;
        c=temp;
    }
    if(b>a){
        temp=a;
        a=b;
        b=temp;
    }
    cout << "smallest: " << a+(b*10)+(c*100) << "\n";
    cout << "biggest: " << (a*100)+(b*10)+c << "\n";
```

If there's some other way, please let me know!